# Ideal place to put a method after orientation has changed

Tags: ios, methods, orientation, autorotate

I have an issue and here how it goes,

I have a view with a subview, the subview is loaded conditionally, only if the parent view is setHidden property is set to YES;

something like [parentView setHidden:YES] and if([parentView isHidden]),

I want to call a method when the orientation changes and that is the cited snippet above, but I have observed that the method **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** is called 4 times during loading and 2 times during runtime, since the method is called more than once, how can I possibly implement a method call *ideally* since apple's existing method doesn't seem to give me the intuitiveness to put my custom method call with the existing method.

If I would **hack** this thing, it is possible, but somebody might have a better idea before resorting to things that in the future would just cause me more trouble than benefit.

TIA

Comment: Use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method. That should be called only once. shouldAutorotate methods are called by the system to find out if the rotation should occur. willRotate methods are called just before rotating. I am assuming, you want to know when it is about to rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // check here for your desired rotation
}
```